# Swing: easiest way to align width of [dynamic][static][dynamic] components?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

What is the easiest way in standard Java Swing to align three components in such a way that:

- the **dynamic widths** of `Component1` and `Component3` are **adjusted to be equal**,
- while `Component2` (which is in between) has **constant** width?

Imagine we have some resizable JPanel (such as inside a JFrame).

**Small width should look like this:**

```
[----------------whole JPanel----------------]
[--Component1--] [Component2] [--Component3--]
```

**Big width should look like this:**

```
[------------------------whole JPanel------------------------]
[------Component1------] [Component2] [------Component3------]
```

*Note: I just "trialed-and-errored" with `GroupLayout` for too long.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using a [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html).  A quick and dirty snippet to get you started:

```
GridBagConstraints gbc;
final int A_CENTER = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;  // anchor: center
final int F_NONE = GridBagConstraints.NONE;  // fill: none
final int F_DX = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;  // fill: dx only
final Insets IN_0 = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);  // empty insets

setLayout(new GridBagLayout() );
gbc = new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 50.0, 0.0, A_CENTER, F_DX, IN_0, 0, 0);
add(new JButton("test1"), gbc);
gbc = new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, A_CENTER, F_NONE, IN_0, 0, 0);
add(new JButton("test2"), gbc);
gbc = new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 1, 1, 50.0, 0.0, A_CENTER, F_DX, IN_0, 0, 0);
add(new JButton("test1"), gbc);
```

Obviously there's a lot more you can do with a GridBag, and you'll need to do some polishing to get exactly what you want to see, but this should get you started.

The fifth parameter in the GBC constructor is a weight for stretching in the x direction.  Setting them equal, and forcing the center component not to stretch (F_NONE) does the dirty work.

Comment: You can reuse GridBagConstraints :P
I would make the left anchor west, right anchor east and the middle one center.

Comment: There's a plethora of ways to use GridBags :)  I just cut and pasted something I'd used lately.  As far as reusing GBC's... I feel it makes the code less readable.  Its hard to see if you just forgot to set one of the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

How about the [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) manager? It is not a part of JRE, but is a great layout manager, which can easily produce the layout you require with less code than GridBag. Check out their [demo](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/swingdemoapp.jnlp).

Could not resist to post the [totally grid bag](http://madbean.com/anim/totallygridbag/) cartoon... enjoy (: